# Maven / Fabric8 - build an OpenShift container image against a remote OpenShift installation

Tags: openshift, fabric8, fabric8-maven-plugin, jkube

With Docker I need only provide DOCKER_HOST and appropriate credentials in order for the fabric8 plugin to be able to build my container image.  As long as a Docker Registry is available - there is no need to install Docker-related infrastructure on the actual host which does the image build (e.g. my Bamboo agent).

With OpenShift I cannot seem to find a way to do this.  It seems instead that I must run the maven goals on a host on which OpenShift has been installed, which must necessarily be a RedHat Linux host.

This seems far more complicated than it should be.  Am I missing something here?

Is there a way to reference a remote OpenShift environment from the fabric8-maven-plugin when in openshift mode?

Thanks, Robin.

Comment: I think plugin works just fine with remote OpenShift environment. It reads your `~/.kube/config` for Cluster Information

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Fabric8 team. You don't need to run goals from host on which OpenShift has been install. Plugin reads your `~/.kube/config` for information related to your OpenShift cluster and uses your API token in order to interact with OpenShift REST API.

[Fabric8 Maven Plugin](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-maven-plugin/) has been migrated to [Eclipse JKube](https://github.com/eclipse/jkube). Although Fabric8 Maven Plugin also works just fine with remote OpenShift Clusters. It's the same Fabric8 Maven Plugin but with a different name and targeted OpenShift Plugin. I would give this answer with Eclipse JKube's [OpenShift Maven Plugin](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:%22org.eclipse.jkube%22%20AND%20a:%22openshift-maven-plugin%22). You can have it in your `pom.xml` like this:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jkube</groupId>
  <artifactId>openshift-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
```

Here is a demo using a simple Random generator application: https://github.com/rohanKanojia/eclipse-jkube-demo-project

1. Log into your OpenShift Cluster with credentials provided:

```sh
~ : $ oc login https://your-cluster.openshift.com--token=your-token
Logged into "https://your-cluster.openshift.com:443" as "rohanKanojia" using the token provided.

You have one project on this server: "rokumar"

Using project "rokumar".
```

2. Go to your project and Issue OpenShift Maven Plugin goals:

```sh
eclipse-jkube-demo-project : $ mvn package oc:build oc:resource oc:apply
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< meetup:random-generator >-----------------------
[INFO] Building random-generator 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ random-generator ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ random-generator ---

...

[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ random-generator ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/rohaan/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-demo-project/target/random-generator-0.0.1.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.3.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) @ random-generator ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- openshift-maven-plugin:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT:build (default-cli) @ random-generator ---
[INFO] oc: Using OpenShift build with strategy S2I
[INFO] oc: Running in OpenShift mode
[INFO] oc: Running generator spring-boot
[INFO] oc: spring-boot: Using Docker image quay.io/jkube/jkube-java-binary-s2i:0.0.8 as base / builder
[INFO] oc: [random-generator:0.0.1] "spring-boot": Created docker source tar /home/rohaan/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-demo-project/target/docker/random-generator/0.0.1/tmp/docker-build.tar
[INFO] oc: Adding to Secret pullsecret-jkube
[INFO] oc: Using Secret pullsecret-jkube
[INFO] oc: Creating BuildServiceConfig random-generator-s2i for Source build
[INFO] oc: Adding to ImageStream random-generator
[INFO] oc: Starting Build random-generator-s2i
[INFO] oc: Waiting for build random-generator-s2i-1 to complete...
[INFO] oc: Using quay.io/jkube/jkube-java-binary-s2i:0.0.8 as the s2i builder image
[INFO] oc: INFO S2I source build with plain binaries detected
[INFO] oc: INFO S2I binary build from fabric8-maven-plugin detected
[INFO] oc: INFO Copying binaries from /tmp/src/deployments to /deployments ...
[INFO] oc: random-generator-0.0.1.jar
[INFO] oc: INFO Copying deployments from deployments to /deployments...
[INFO] oc: '/tmp/src/deployments/random-generator-0.0.1.jar' -> '/deployments/random-generator-0.0.1.jar'
[INFO] oc: INFO Cleaning up source directory (/tmp/src)
[INFO] oc: 
[INFO] oc: Pushing image 172.30.39.149:5000/rokumar/random-generator:0.0.1 ...
[INFO] oc: Pushed 0/4 layers, 19% complete
[INFO] oc: Pushed 1/4 layers, 25% complete
[INFO] oc: Push successful
[INFO] oc: Build random-generator-s2i-1 in status Complete
[INFO] oc: Found tag on ImageStream random-generator tag: sha256:51756e1ff9b639c939f3c0c9246ab4ed924faa269bc9cbf05035c859d19fa50c
[INFO] oc: ImageStream random-generator written to /home/rohaan/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-demo-project/target/random-generator-is.yml
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- openshift-maven-plugin:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT:resource (default-cli) @ random-generator ---
[INFO] oc: Using docker image name of namespace: rokumar
[INFO] oc: Running generator spring-boot
[INFO] oc: spring-boot: Using Docker image quay.io/jkube/jkube-java-binary-s2i:0.0.8 as base / builder
[INFO] oc: jkube-controller: Adding a default DeploymentConfig
[INFO] oc: jkube-service: Adding a default service 'random-generator' with ports [8080]
[INFO] oc: jkube-healthcheck-spring-boot: Adding readiness probe on port 8080, path='/actuator/health', scheme='HTTP', with initial delay 10 seconds
[INFO] oc: jkube-healthcheck-spring-boot: Adding liveness probe on port 8080, path='/actuator/health', scheme='HTTP', with initial delay 180 seconds
[INFO] oc: jkube-revision-history: Adding revision history limit to 2
[INFO] oc: validating /home/rohaan/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-demo-project/target/classes/META-INF/jkube/openshift/random-generator-service.yml resource
[INFO] oc: validating /home/rohaan/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-demo-project/target/classes/META-INF/jkube/openshift/random-generator-route.yml resource
[INFO] oc: validating /home/rohaan/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-demo-project/target/classes/META-INF/jkube/openshift/random-generator-deploymentconfig.yml resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- openshift-maven-plugin:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT:apply (default-cli) @ random-generator ---
[INFO] oc: Using OpenShift at https://api.rh-idev.openshift.com:443/ in namespace rokumar with manifest /home/rohaan/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-demo-project/target/classes/META-INF/jkube/openshift.yml 
[INFO] oc: OpenShift platform detected
[INFO] oc: Using project: rokumar
[INFO] oc: Creating a Service from openshift.yml namespace rokumar name random-generator
[INFO] oc: Created Service: target/jkube/applyJson/rokumar/service-random-generator.json
[INFO] oc: Creating a DeploymentConfig from openshift.yml namespace rokumar name random-generator
[INFO] oc: Created DeploymentConfig: target/jkube/applyJson/rokumar/deploymentconfig-random-generator.json
[INFO] oc: Creating Route rokumar:random-generator host: null
[INFO] oc: HINT: Use the command `oc get pods -w` to watch your pods start up
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:02 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-29T10:57:34+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

3. Access your application deployed into OpenShift

```sh
eclipse-jkube-demo-project : $ oc get routes
NAME                      HOST/PORT                                                        PATH      SERVICES                  PORT      TERMINATION   WILDCARD
random-generator          random-generator-rokumar.b6ff.rh-idev.openshiftapps.com                    random-generator          8080                    None
weather-web-application   weather-web-application-rokumar.b6ff.rh-idev.openshiftapps.com             weather-web-application   8080                    None
eclipse-jkube-demo-project : $ curl random-generator-rokumar.b6ff.rh-idev.openshiftapps.com/random | jq .
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    45    0    45    0     0     56      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    56
{
  "id": "d79ca3fd-4505-43d1-9920-a39ac15a3b49"
}
```

For more information, you can checkout [Eclipse JKube Quickstarts](https://www.eclipse.org/jkube/quickstarts/)

Comment: This looks good and I will be trying it out as soon as I have OC installed.  But, is there any expectation that the "oc login" might become internal to the plugin, such that even OC does not have to be locally installed?

Comment: All plugin needs is `~/.kube/config` file with correct cluster information(oc login just changes context to your current cluster). If you already have a correctly configured `kubeconfig` in your system from where you want to deploy. You won't even need `oc`. Plugin doesn't depend on `oc` and uses OpenShift REST API

Comment: I have no kubeconfig file at this time and am using "oc login".  After successful login I execute mvn oc:build (package was previously completed).  I see the following error:  Unknown host kubernetes.default.svc   Any ideas?  My OpenShift 4.3 project is effectively empty.  Any ideas?

Comment: that's strange. I've never seen kubeconfig file not being created, it's required by both `oc` and `kubectl`. Could you please join our Gitter channel so that we can discuss your problem in detail there: https://gitter.im/eclipse/jkube

Comment: Maybe your `.kube/config` file is not present in expected location. What output do you get when you do `oc config view`. What's the value of `KUBECONFIG` environment variable?